# I can't start the android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

For some time now I haven't been able to start Android emulators with api >= 28.
The emulator display remains black.
However, with Android API versions <= 27 it is ok.

*PC:
Intel i7-13700F
GeForce RTX 4060
16GB DDR*

Can you help me please?

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio and plugins several times.
Someone in another forum mentioned possible problems with the graphics controller drivers